# WPF determine all keys released in textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, keydown

I wanted to make user to customise the shortcut keys, so I'm using a textbox to get the key input. The expected state should be to save the key when pressed, and show KeyGesture string when released.

But some keys will be responded to by other registered hotkeys ( like Ctrl+A, win+G etc. ) ,  unable to determine whether if the keys are all released, so that cannot clear ModifierKeys when appropriate.

Here's my code, if input a registered hotkey this *keyCount* will be wrong:

```
KeyGestureConverter keyGestureConverter = new KeyGestureConverter();
Key key;
ModifierKeys modifierKeys;
int keyCount = 0;

private void HotKeyTextbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key.Equals(Key.LeftCtrl) || e.Key.Equals(Key.RightCtrl))
        modifierKeys |= ModifierKeys.Control;
    else if (e.Key.Equals(Key.LeftAlt) || e.Key.Equals(Key.RightAlt))
        modifierKeys |= ModifierKeys.Alt;
    else if (e.Key.Equals(Key.LeftShift) || e.Key.Equals(Key.RightShift))
        modifierKeys |= ModifierKeys.Shift;
    else if (e.Key.Equals(Key.LWin) || e.Key.Equals(Key.RWin))
        modifierKeys |= ModifierKeys.Windows;
    else
        key = e.Key;
    keyCount++;
}

private void HotKeyTextbox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    keyCount--;
    try
    {
        KeyGesture keyGesture = new KeyGesture(key, modifierKeys);
        HotKeyTextbox.Text = keyGestureConverter.ConvertToString(keyGesture);
    }
    catch
    {
        HotKeyTextbox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    if (keyCount <= 0)
    {
        keyCount = 0;
        key = Key.None;
        modifierKeys = ModifierKeys.None;
    }
}
```

How about achieving the right effect?

Comment: You must handle the PrevieKeyDown and PreviewKeyUp  events to catch common key gestures before they got handled by the TextBox.

Comment: @tp1415926535: Could you please clarify your issue? What results are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must handle the `PreviewKeyDown` and `PreviewKeyUp` events to catch common key gestures before they got handled by the `TextBox`. `TextBox` will handle certain gestures like "Ctrl+C" and then mark the event as handled.

To print a key combination simply use the `KeyGesture.GetDisplayStringForCulture` method (see example below).
To register a handler for the recorded gesture, simply define new [`KeyBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keybinding?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#examples) and add it to the appropriate `UIElement.InputBindings` collection. But to make sense, you would have to let the user select the key command (action) first. Otherwise you don't know to which action the gesture should map to.
The following example assumes that the selected action is already stored in the `SelectedGestureCommand` property.

To handle/override globally registered key gestures like your mentioned "Windows+G", you would have to use P/Invoke to handle those events on OS level. There is no WPF API for this task.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<TextBox PreviewKeyDown="RecordGesture_OnKeyDown"
         PreviewKeyUp="PrintRecordedGesture_OnKeyUp" />
```

**MainWindow.xamlcs**

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  // Register the predefined gestures that the user can later modify.
  // TODO::Define the required commands by implementing ICommand for each
  this.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(DoSomethingCommand, Key.A, ModifierKeys.Shift | ModifierKeys.Alt));
}

private void RecordGesture_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  var newGesture = new KeyGesture(e.Key, e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers);

  // Update the existing action with the new gesture
  KeyBinding selectedKeyBinding = this.InputBindings
    .OfType<KeyBinding>()
    .First(keyBinding => keyBinding.Command == this.SelectedGestureCommand);
  selectedKeyBinding.Gesture = newGesture;
}

private void PrintRecordedGesture_OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  var currentGesture = new KeyGesture(e.Key, e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers);

  // Print the new gesture
  (sender as TextBox).Text = currentGesture.GetDisplayStringForCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Comment: Good Advice! A little modification would have solved my question: 1. *e.key* includes *e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers* in PreviewKeyDown, needs to be ruled out in advance. 2. PreviewKeyUp will be triggered multiple times, will override causing only the last released key to be displayed. so just show the text in PreviewKeyDown event.

Comment: 1. No, Key only contains a single key. Modifiers are keys pressed while a primary key is pressed. If you press e.g. Ctrl alone, then yes, Key will be Key.Control.2. This is the basic example which will get you to the point to solve your problem. You would have to implement a more complex logic based on your flow. For example, let the user select an action that he wants to record a shortcut for. Then selecting this action starts recording: all keys pressed are printed and assembled to the final shortcut, even when not all keys are pressed simultaneously. The user then commits his new shortcut.

Comment: You didn't show any relevant code. So you got the basic answer that shows you how to handle key input properly and how to register the gesture with an action/command. It answers you posted question perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : misunderstood the question, this is for when shortcuts have already been recorded.

```
private void Key_Down(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control) // With CTRL
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
        case Key.Escape:
            Close();
            break;
        case Key.Y:
            Validate_Data();
            break;
        }
    }
    else // Without CRTL
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Escape:
                Close();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well... do you mean to handle the other methods directly in the keydown event? But what I need is to let the user customize the shortcut keys, not a preset comparison. The Textbox is used to set shortcuts which are global rather than responsive in the textbox.

Comment: You can adapt it. For example, change `case Key.Escape` to `case Key.TryParse(textbox1.Text)`. Of course you have to make sure that the input in the textbox is checked. Or store the custom shortcut in variables / properties and check the correspondance.

Comment: I'm asking about the situation when custom shortcuts are being acquired, not the situation where user settings have already been acquired. I can't clear the KeyGesture properly after it is interrupted.

Comment: Okay, sorry. My answer is not relevant.